# Overlay wav files at different start times using Pydub

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pydub

I have a series of wav files I would like to combine and export as a single wav using Pydub. I would like the audio from the original files to play back at different times in the exported file e.g. the audio in `audio_1.wav` starts at time=0 in the exported file while the audio in `audio_2.wav` starts at time=5 instead of both starting at time=0 as the `overlay` function has them. Is there any way to do this? Below is the code I currently have for importing, overlaying, and exporting the audio files.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

audio_1 = AudioSegment.from_file("audio_1.wav",
                               format="wav")

audio_2 = AudioSegment.from_file("audio_2.wav",
                               format="wav")

overlay = vln_audio_1.overlay(vla_audio_2)
file_handle = overlay.export("output2.wav", format="wav")
```

Comment: did you check what you have in files - maybe second file has 5 seconds of silences at start and this is all problem.

Comment: No, that's what I want. Currently all files start at the same time with no silence.

Comment: maybe you should first add some silence at the beginning. `silence = AudioSegment.silent(duration=5000)`  and `audio_2 = silence + audio_2`

Comment: based on [documentation](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown#audiosegmentoverlay) it may need `overlay(..., position=5000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test it but based on [documentation](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/blob/master/API.markdown#audiosegmentoverlay) it may need `overlay(..., position=5000)`

---

**BTW:**

you may also add `silence` at the beginning to move audio

```
silence_5_seconds = AudioSegment.silent(duration=5000)

audio_2 = silence_5_seconds + audio_2
```

Comment: Thanks, this ended up working.